# Foreign attribute in arff

Tags: csv, weka, arff

Assume I have several arff (lets call it `set`) files in format

```
@attribute foo
@attribute foo1
@attribute bar


some data
```

`foo` is same for every data row in each arff file (every arff file has it owns `foo` attribute) from `set`.

Also I have one `csv` file with headers

```
foo, baz, bar
```

Attribute `foo` is sort of "foreign key".

How can I load them all together into weka so weka knows when it reads some arff file from `set` it should read also corresponding entry from `csv` file?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any direct way. It needs to be done programmatically.